# Why would you increment using i = (i +1) & mask, where mask is 0b1111?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I was looking at the source code for `ArrayDeque.contains(Object o)` when I found this implementation:

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if this deque contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this deque contains
 * at least one element {@code e} such that {@code o.equals(e)}.
 *
 * @param o object to be checked for containment in this deque
 * @return {@code true} if this deque contains the specified element
 */
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if (o == null)
        return false;
    int mask = elements.length - 1;
    int i = head;
    Object x;
    while ( (x = elements[i]) != null) {
        if (o.equals(x))
            return true;
        i = (i + 1) & mask;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here, the array size is an exponent of 2, so `mask` should be a binary number with all 1's. It seems to me that `i = (i + 1) & mask` does the exact same thing as `i = i + 1`. Could anyone tell me why this was implemented this way?

Comment: It is to limit `i` to be less than the array size... That if `i` reaches the end of the array, it continues on the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line applies a fast version of a modulo limited increment operation.

```
i = (i + 1) & (length - 1);
```

For length 8 you get

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
4 -> 5
5 -> 6
6 -> 7
7 -> 0
```

You know a similar behavior from the clock (nearly, as we usally start clock with 1 instead of 0),

There is an constraint, length must be able to be written as 2^n, 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,....

It works because the bit representation of (2^n)-1 are a mask with n ones.
For example (2^5)-1 is binary 0b00011111.

Any number 0 <= x < 2^n will pass a mask (2^n)-1 without change. The number 2^n will be set to 0 when the mask will be applied.

The more general approach is to use modulo %. but modulo is usally much slower than bit manipulations like "and" (&)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the implementation but this looks like a "cyclic array". `head` is the index of the first element and by incrementing and masking the iteration loops around the bounds.

The "last" slot in the array is always empty (`== null`) which would end the iteration if the object is not found, and `false` will be returned.

Comment: So is it the same as `i = (i + 1) % elements.length`?

Answer (score 2):

This is done to wrap a counter around. As you already said, if the number of elements is a power of 2, so `elements.length -1` will be all bits 1.

```
mask = 7  // we assume a elements.length of 8
x = (x + 1) & mask  // will be 7 and 7, so result is 7
```

now we increment again

```
x = (x + 1) & mask // now it is 8 and 7, so result will be zero
```

Other, maybe more readable, approaches that achieve the same result would be:

```
if (x < elements.length) x=x+1 else x=0;

x = x < elements.length ? x+1 : 0;

x = (x + 1) % elements.length;
```

but masking it is just a speed (not a readability ) improvement.

Comment: Or could use "modulo", EG `i = (i+1) % size`

Comment: Is there a performance advantage over using the modulo operator, as @UsagiMiyamoto mentioned?

Comment: My assembly times are long gone, but I think  modulo will internally be implemented using the bitmask. @UsagiMiyamoto, what do you think?

Comment: Only if the compiler could statically prove that the divisor is a power of two (and that the dividend is non-negative but there is still a trick available if it isn't). That's not likely here since the length comes from some random array that the compiler knows nothing about.

Comment: Pass... BTW, i do not think modulo can be optimized to bitmask, especially, if it uses a variable...

Comment: @harold ok, after having a look at your profile, now I would really like to hear about the trick with negative numbers to learn. ;-)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto almost all optimization is done at JIT-compile time though..

Comment: @Arminius the most obvious way is computing `a & b` and `-(-a & b)` and then deciding which one to take based on the sign of `a` (which can be a branchless-select). Or you could use conditional negation based on the sign (mostly like a branchless abs). Perhaps there is a better way but that's what I know

Comment: Just had a chance to look at your comment. Thanks a lot, will give it a try on the wekeend!